# Adding the values of the keys

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Please consider the following snapshot of array of structures:

[image]

My Database Schema is as follows:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25eeb

I want to calculate the sum of the values of the structure keys and store the total into the database. For example, I want to store, 146+1 = 147 value under blocked column, similarly, 4+1+2 = 7 in the bounce column etc.

So far, I have been accessing the keys which was pretty straightforward, in the following manner ( as shown in the Insert statement):

```
 <cfquery datasource="XX.XX.X.XX" name="qCoulmnInsert">
INSERT INTO 
             mytable (blocked_int,
                      bounce_int,
                      date_dt,
                      deferred_int,
                      delivered_int,
                       drop_int                                                                                                                      

                                                                        )

  VALUES
              <!--- loop through your array --->
             <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(cfData)#" index="i">
             ( <!--- 1 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "blocked")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["blocked"]["Other"]#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL

              </cfif> ,
              <!--- 2 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "bounce")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["bounce"]["At & T"]#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,
```

I am wondering, is there a way to sum up the values of the keys because as clear from the image, the keys are not fixed for blocked,bounce,deferred etc.

Please advise.

**ERROR:**

After running the below mentioned approach, I am gettign the following error:

```
The value Cox cannot be converted to a number.

The error occurred in C:myfile.cfm: line 38

36 :             <cfset total = 0>
37 :             <cfloop item="subkey" collection="#struct[key]#">
38 :                 <cfset total += subkey>
39 :             </cfloop>
40 :             <cfset totals[key] = total>
```

Not sure what is Cox here?

Also, if I talk in the context of INSERT statement, how would I fit it around `<cfqueryparam>` tag where I have to define the total value?

Please advise.

**Further Question:**

Okay, so I have the following output based on the example mentioned below:

[image]

I want to insert the date and the values of it's keys in a single column in the database.
I want to repeat the same for all the dates.

So here is what I attempted to do:

```
<cfquery datasource="10.11.0.130" name="qCoulmnInsert">
INSERT INTO 
   simplexresults.contactresults_email_account_summary_isps     (date_dt,
                                                                                                     blocked_int,
                                                                 bounce_int,
                                                                 deferred_int,
                                                                 delivered_int,
                                                                 drop_int,
                                                                 open_int,
                                                                 processed_int,
                                                                 request_int,
                                                                 spamreport_int,  
                                                                 uniqueopen_int
                                                                                                                                                              )

  VALUES
              <!--- loop through your structure --->
             <cfloop from="1" to="#StructCount(totals)#" index="i">
             ( <!--- 1 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[i], "blocked")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[i].blocked#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL

              </cfif> ,
              <!--- 2 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[i], "bounce")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[i]["bounce"]">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,
```

The above thing doesn't work. Also, since date is variable now, how should I handle it?

Here is my sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d135f

Please advise.

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

I have been using the following code after "VALUES" clause and getting one error:

```
VALUES

<cfloop collection="#totals#" item="theDate">
             ( 





              <!--- 1 --->
             <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "blocked")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[theDate].blocked#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL

              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 2 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "bounce")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[theDate].bounce#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,


              <!--- 3 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "deferred")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[theDate].deferred#">
               <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 4 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "delivered")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[theDate].delivered#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 5 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "drop")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[theDate].drop#">
               <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 6 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "open")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[theDate].open#">
               <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 7 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "processed")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[theDate].processed#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 8 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "request")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[theDate].request#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 9 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "spamreport")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[theDate].spamreport#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 10 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "unique_open")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#totals[theDate].unique_open#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,




              <!--- FOR DATES --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "startdate_dt")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#totals[theDate].startdate_dt#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif>, 



              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "enddate_dt")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#totals[theDate].enddate_dt#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif>,



              <cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "date")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#totals[theDate].date#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif>  

              )

             <!---  <cfif i neq arrayLen(cfData)>,</cfif> --->
          </cfloop>
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Error Executing Database Query.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( ' at line 86

The error occurred in C:\myfile.cfm: line 67
Called from C:\myfolder\application.cfc: line 211
Called from C:\myfile.cfm: line 67
Called from C:\myfoldert\application.cfc: line 211

65 :   VALUES
66 :               <!--- loop through your array --->
67 :              <cfloop collection="#totals#" item="theDate">
68 :              ( 
69 :
```

I don't know why it is throwing error at line #67. Because, when I tested it as follows,
I got my output without any error:

```
<cfloop collection="#totals#" item="theDate">


Blocked:<cfoutput>#totals[theDate].blocked#</cfoutput>
Bounce: <cfoutput>#totals[theDate].bounce#</cfoutput>


</cfloop>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks

**UPDATED Question as of Feb 07**

When I used the following , I am getting one more error:

```
VALUES

<cfloop from = "1" to="#arrayLen(dateArray)#" index="i">
             ( 

          <!--- get current date --->

         <cfset theDate = dateArray[i]>

         <!--- append a comma in between value sets --->

         <cfif i gt 1>,</cfif>



              <!--- 1 --->
             <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "blocked")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].blocked#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL

              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 2 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "bounce")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].bounce#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,


              <!--- 3 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "deferred")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].deferred#">
               <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 4 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "delivered")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].delivered#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 5 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "drop")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].drop#">
               <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 6 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "open")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].open#">
               <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 7 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "processed")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].processed#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 8 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "request")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].request#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 9 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "spamreport")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].spamreport#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,

              <!--- 10 --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "unique_open")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].unique_open#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif> ,




              <!--- FOR DATES --->
              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "startdate_dt")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#dateArray[i].startdate_dt#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif>, 



              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "enddate_dt")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#dateArray[i].enddate_dt#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif>,



              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "date")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#dateArray[i].date#">
              <cfelse>
                 NULL
              </cfif>  

              )

             <!---  <cfif i neq arrayLen(cfData)>,</cfif> --->
          </cfloop>
```

Here is the **Error** I am getting:

You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.

```
The error occurred in C:myfile.cfm: line 94

92 :               <!--- 1 --->
93 :               <!--- <cfif isStruct("blocked")> --->
94 :              <cfif structKeyExists(dateArray[i], "blocked")>
95 :                 <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#dateArray[i].blocked#">
96 :               <cfelse>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I am assuming coldfusion is not linking accessing converted date array as Structkeyexists in the cfif check but even testing it separately like the following is producing the same error:

```
<cfloop from = "1" to="#arrayLen(dateArray)#" index="i">

<cfoutput>#dateArray[i].blocked#</cfoutput>

</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So firstly loop over your struct.  Secondly check if the content of that struct element is itself a struct (so we can eliminate the 'date' key).  Then loop over that struct totalling up the values of its keys.  Something a little like this perhaps.  I've used a separate struct just to hold the totals.  I'd then loop over only that struct to update the DB.

```
<cfset totals = {}>

<cfloop index="struct" array="#cfData#">
    <cfset totals[struct.date] = {}>
    <cfloop item="key" collection="#struct#">
        <cfif isStruct(struct[key])>
            <cfset total = 0>
            <cfloop item="subkey" collection="#struct[key]#">
                <cfset total += struct[key][subkey]>
            </cfloop>
            <cfset totals[struct.date][key] = total>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Also, you may want to initialize the totals first. ie `totals = {bounced=0,deferred=0,...}`. Then the necessary keys will always exist, which will greatly simplify your `insert` code.

Comment: @duncan Thanks but I am getting one error. Please check my original question.

Comment: ok i updated my answer, instead of adding up `subkey` you need to add up `struct[key][subkey]`

Comment: @duncan ok, the error disappeared, so when I tested it like this `<cfdump var="#total#">` , I don't know why, I am getting only one and same value irrespective of the arraylength. Am I testing it wrong?In order to see the total for each elements, I tried to do something like this `<cfoutput>#total[blocked]#"</cfoutput> ` but it's throwing error.

Comment: Do you want to calculate 1 value for 'blocked' (etc) across all the array elements?  If so I think if we use @Leigh's suggestion of initialising it.  Then change `<cfset totals[key] = total>` to `<cfset totals[key] += total>`

Comment: @duncan - Actually I misread your example. Did not notice the structure was initialized *outside* the array loop. Anyway, my thinking was init/re-init the structure for *each* element in the array. So you end up with totals for *each* individual date (ie array element).  Not sure if that is what the OP is looking for, but .. that is what I had in mind.

Comment: @duncan For each array element I want one value of 'blocked' (etc). therefore for each and every unique date value in each array, I can insert the values of 'blocked' (etc). My database schema is defined in sqlfiddle: `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25eeb`. Changing it to `<cfset totals[key] += total>` is still giving me the same value 23135 when I used `<cfdump var="#total#">`

Comment: Please let me know if my question isn't clear. I will probably provide an example in my question.

Comment: I made a slight amendment to my answer. Have the main struct keyed on each date.  Within that should be a struct for each of the main categories, 'bounce','blocked' etc.  Ignore my previous comment about using +=

Comment: @duncan Thanks but `<cfdump var="#total#">` is still showing me the same value 23135. I don't know from where this value is totalling.

Comment: Can you stick your full code, including the original array, online somewhere?

Comment: @user3239126 - Duncan's updated example works correctly. Are you certain you are using the *new* example? Also, I think you are dumping the wrong variable. If you want to see the overall totals, by date, dump the `totals` structure - not "total".

Comment: I apologize. I was dumping total and not totals for seeing overall totals. I think I am good without date as well so, I removed it and I can see the total of blocked etc inside a structure. By the way, how would I include such complex thing into `<cfqueryparam>` value field in order to insert it into database ?

Comment: @duncan Could you also take a look at my updated question? Thanks

Comment: @user3239126 - `totals` is a structure, not an array. You have to loop through the structure keys (ie your date values). Use a collection loop instead:  `<cfloop collection="#totals#" item="theDate"> ... #totals[theDate].blocked#...`

Comment: @Leigh Thanks Leigh. I did the adjustment but I am getting error in one scenario and it's running fine in other scenario. Could you please take a look at my "Updated Question".

Comment: Does the order of the columns you're inserting match the order you specify them?  Your original question had the date_dt column first, but your updated code seems to have it last.

Comment: @user3239126  
Oh, I think I see the problem. Each set of data in the `values` clause must separated by a comma. By removing this statement `<cfif i neq arrayLen(cfData)>,</cfif>`, it also removes the comma, so the sql is no longer valid. You either need to add a manual counter variable OR switch back to a from/to loop - but with a slight twist. http://pastebin.com/PmkijUM2

Comment: @Leigh Could you tell me why is `<cfif i neq arrayLen(cfData)>,</cfif>` required, I didn't understand this part. Rest of the SQL statement seems to be fine.

Comment: @user3239126 - You need it to generate a valid sql statement. [Multiple `values` **MUST** be separated by a comma](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html). If you omit the comma, your sql will look like this (and will error): `VALUES (1,2,3) [missing comma here] (4,5,6) [missing comma here] (7,8,9)`. Missing commas are the cause of your earlier syntax error "You have an error in your SQL syntax;..."

Comment: @Leigh I have updated my original question under "Updated as of Feb 07" based on your approach with the error. Could you please take a look? Thanks

Comment: I think you are getting confused with the combination loop. You still need to use `theDate` key for the cfqyeryparam elements, like in your earlier example ie `<cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "blocked")>`

Comment: @Leigh Thanks a lot. It worked. You are really good in explaining things, especially when you explained the missing comma related confusion I had which I wasn't able to imagine by looking at the giant code I was working on. Thanks again. Appreciated.

Comment: By the way, one question out of curiosity, what if I want to insert the date as well in my table along with total values of blocked, bounce etc. Wondering since date doesn't have it's key value as another structure, would that be difficult to do so?

Comment: You are welcome. *RE: would that be difficult to do so* Nope. Just use `#theDate#` ;-)

Comment: That's true. It is inserting by using `<cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#theDate#">` and it's inserting dates in random order, however, I am not able to check using something like `<cfif structKeyExists(totals[theDate], "date")> ` in this case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47051/discussion-between-leigh-and-user3239126)